# How to parse user from access_token?

Tags: laravel, axios, laravel-passport

I currently have 2 servers: 1 Laravel backend/API server, 1 frontend server that runs a Vue SPA.

The issue I run into is an authentication issue. From my Vue app I can login successfully through API authentication, using a Password Grant.

An axios request will hit the auth endpoint which will:

```
$response = $http->post(env('APP_URL').'/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'username' => $credentials['email'],
        'password' => $credentials['password'],
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);
```

In return I receive the tokens which I store in localStorage. At some later step in my Vue app, I am trying to make another API request for that logged in user, using the tokens I received from the password grant.

```
let config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + state.tokens.access_token}
};

window.axios.post('/purchases', {
    form: state.form,
}, config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response);       
    });
```

But I receive a 401 error

> Error: "Unauthenticated."

I assumed that the `auth:api` middleware would parse the access token to the user, but it seems to not.

How can I parse the user that once my `/purchases` endpoint gets hit, I can access the user `$request->user()`?

Comment: Check your request header if the token is correctly set?

Comment: @chris you are vuex if yes.at each refresh your storage destroy instead of vuex store it in localstorage it will not create any security issue but remember after login or browser close clear this thing

Comment: @MuhammadNauman Yes, it is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

hello chris there are 2 way

**method 1**

```
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {


   axios.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] =store.state.userStore.authUser //this is globaly defind header
      //put your login over here
 }
});
```

in this I m set axios header at each request

**method 2**

pass your token in your url something like this 
    suppose you url like localhost/laravel/public/api/anyname?access_token='+localstoragevalue

Comment: Thanks! Don't get me wrong, I do not have an issue passing the token in the header. The issue I have is getting the user from it.

Comment: @Chris  store token and well as userid into another table after login i.e wright code in login controller and another method is that create extra column in user table (token column) and this process will be follow in both method  create middleware to check which user its belongs for eg:-find where token it is request token if found make him login else redirect to home page after that all thing will be remain same  as normal login without token